# How to tell if Debezium has any unstreamed changes to stream to Kafka?

Tags: sql-server, cdc, debezium

I'm looking to use Debezium to stream changes (in CDC) from a bunch of tables in some MS SQL Server databases to Kafka. These tables will have evolving structure.

In order to alter captured columns, I must:

1. Stop publishing new data
2. **Wait for Debezium to stream any unstreamed changes to Kafka**
3. Disable CDC
4. Make the changes to the schema(s)
5. Enable CDC
6. ...

However, how do I know that Debezium has finished streaming all changes to Kafka? I can't find any documentation about any API/endpoint in Debezium that tells me its status. Also, is there any API/endpoint I can hit between (1) and (2) to specifically instruct Debezium to flush the CDC changes to Kafka immediately?

Thanks

Comment: Is your set of steps something from the Debezium documentation, or an assumption that you're making?

Comment: I'm paraphrasing from here: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/sqlserver.html#sqlserver-schema-evolution, why?

Comment: It's Step 2 of the described (safer) cold schema update that I need feedback on from Debezium.

Comment: It's useful information to include in your question, because it gives people background and further understanding of your question, that's why I asked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the safest approach is comparing the database LSN with LSN that is stored in connector offsets. This way wou are sure which changes the connector has seen and committed to the Kafka.

Comment: Is this the only way? My deployment of Debezium will be in a shared environment and most services won't have direct access to the source database.